# Why don't I see my tokens in Mist?

Tags: mist, tokens, accounts, erc-20

I think I should have several tokens in my account, but I can only see Ether. Is a wallet contract necessary to see ERC-20 tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the token contract to mist.
Unless they've updated the interface, you do it like this:

1. Click on the "Contracts" button
2. Scroll to the bottom and click "Watch Token"
3. Enter the token contract address in the "Token Contract Address" field
4. Enter its name in the "Token Name" field
5. Enter its symbol in the "Token Symbol" field
6. Enter the decimal units in the "Decimal Places of Smallest Units"
   Press OK